# Texstudio editor sometimes stops accepting inputs

Tags: texstudio, mac

I have Texstudio-4.4.1 on macOS Big Sur (11.7.1) and the editor frequently ignores my keyboard inputs.

This first happened last week when I was still using Texstudio-4.3.0 on macOS Catalina (10.15.8). I tried to address this issue by updating Texstudio from 4.3.0 to 4.4.1. Since this didn't work out, I upgraded my macOS from 10.15.8 to 11.7.1. I have also reinstalled Texstudio multiple times, both by compiling it from source and directly installing the dmg file provided by https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/download/4.4.1/texstudio-4.4.1-osx.dmg

However, this issue does not disappear. Originally, it happens several times within a day. Now it occurs every few minutes, which is intolerable. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try another keyboard?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't try another keyboard. But since the VScode and other apps work fine, I don't think it's due to the physical keyboard.

Comment: Well you should report that to the texstudio bug tracker,  but you should first try with another keyboard as that will probably the first question.